# Is it possible to open a iOS keyboard extension via a URL?

Tags: ios, keyboard, url-scheme, ios-keyboard-extension

I know that via an app's URL scheme, you can click a link that opens in an app. Now I want to know if you can click on a link, say in WhatsApp or iMessage, that will open up a keyboard extension (i.e. my app is a keyboard app). Is there at all a way or a workaround?

Comment: This question is too broad for this site.  Take a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some help on asking

Comment: I hope it has been improved.